# How to correctly return a string from a class?

Tags: java, class

In my main method I have the code..

```
    String FactoredForm = FactoredForm.getFF(gcd1, gcd2, a, hii);
```

And the FactoredForm class is:

```
public class FactoredForm {
public static String forName(int l, int o, int a, int hii) {
    // (lx+o)(mx+p      
    String FF1, FF2;
    if (o > 0){
        FF1 = ("(" + l + "x+" + o + ")");
    }
    else{
        FF1 = ("(" + l + "x" + o + ")");
    }
    if (hii/o > 0){
        FF2 = ("(" + a/l + "x+" + hii/o + ")");
    }
    else{
        FF2 = ("(" + a/l + "x" + hii/o + ")");
    }
    String FactoredForm = (FF1+FF2);


    return FactoredForm;
}
}
```

I get the error that the method getFF is undefined for the type String. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have the String name same as the class name. That's causing the error.

Comment: You absolutely *can* give the variable the same name as the class. You then just need to disambiguate it for the compiler. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @JesusSqueegee: As mentioned in the previous comment, this answer is factually incorrect. You definitely *can* name a variable the same as a class. You shouldn't, but you *can*.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your method is defined as `forName()` but you're calling `getFF()`.

Additionally, you don't want to be doing:

```
String FactoredForm = (FF1+FF2);
```

`FactoredForm` is the name of your class. Just replace the last two lines of your method with:

```
return FF1 + FF2;
```

Comment: whoops. I had them both as getFF() and got the same error. What else am I missing?

Comment: @JesusSqueegee See CodeBlue's answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address the problem that is shown in the question, namely that it's looking for the method in the `string` class due to the name of the variable.

Answer (score 4):

There are two *errors* here:

- In the calling code, you're declaring a variable with the same name as a class, so when you use the same name in the method invocation, the compiler thinks you're talking about the variable. It's not that you *can't* declare a variable with that name - it's just that at that point you'd have to go out of your way to explicitly refer to the class.
- You're trying to call a method which doesn't exist (`getFF` instead of `forName`)

Additionally, declaring a local variable to have the same name as the class makes for pretty unreadable code. It's not *incorrect*, just a bad idea.

All you really *have* to do is use the right method name and convince the compiler that you're talking about the class, not the variable:

```
// Assuming FactoredForm is in the foo package
String FactoredForm = foo.FactoredForm.forName(gcd1, gcd2, a, hii);
```

... but using more conventional variable names (`factoredForm` for example) would be a very good idea. (Typically variables are `camelCased` in Java.)

The above workaround won't work where `FactoredForm` is in the top-level package, but I'd suggest that's another bad practice too.

Comment: Actually now that I look closely it seems you're answering with C# in mind while this is a Java question. Not much would change, but `global::` would instead need to be `FactoredForm`'s package and maybe a link to Java naming conventions instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the method to match the call you are making:

```
public class FactoredForm {
    public static String getFF(int l, int o, int a, int hii) {
    ...
```